# Cordova saving a file within the www folder

Tags: javascript, cordova, file-transfer, cordova-plugins

I am currently creating a Cordova app to save files and read files. I ahve successfully managed to code it up so that it reads a file from the device (or creates it if it does not exist) and then write to that file.

The problem I am having is that it is saving the file to the root of the device. I added in a getDirectory method to create a new directory under the root where the file can sit and this is working but ideally I would like to save the file within the www folder of my Cordova app. Is this possible? Also is there any way of making sure the user is unable to write to this file?

Answer (score 1):

The www folder is in readonly mode. You can't write anything in it.

[Cordova plugin file](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#file-system-layouts) documentation explain this.